# Number Files in Folder

Tags: powershell, rename

I have to rename several episodes that Kodi (Home Cinema Program) lists them correct. I have a folder an just want to rename file by file to `1x01`, `1x02`, `1x03`, etc.

Here is what I got so far but it seems not to work.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
$path = Read-Host "please Path!"
$files = gci $path
$count = 0
$files | Rename-Item -NewName {"1x0"+($count+1)+".mkv"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `$count+1` takes the value of `$count`, adds 1 to it, and returns the result. The value of the variable remains unchanged, so every rename operation uses the same name.

Consider using a `for` loop since you want to number your files anyway:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem $path)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  $newname = "1x{0:d2}{1}" -f ($i+1), $files[$i].Extension
  Rename-Item $files[$i].FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it now:

```
$path = Read-Host "please Path!"

$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
  $extension = $_.Extension
  $newName = "1x0{0:d1}{1}" -f $i, $extension
  $i++
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```